# inserindo dados em web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma aplicação SPA e esta consome uma API REST feito em ASP.NET WebAPI.

Ao tentar realizar um *insert* na API, é retornado o seguinte erro:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

No **`web.config`** do WebAPI configurei assim:

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
```

Não sei porque acontece isso.

No angular:

```
 $scope.inserirCarro = function () {
    var carro = {
        CarroNome: $scope.nome,
        MinCod: $scope.selectMin
    };

    var carroData = crudService.IncluirCarro(carro);
    carroData.then(function (data) {
        getCarros();

        if (data.status == 200) {
            toastr["success"]("Registro cadastrado com sucesso!", "Sistema");
        }

    }, function () {
        toastr["error"]("Erro ao incluir!", "Sistema");
    });
}
```

Service no angular:

```
 this.IncluirCarro = function (carro) {
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: urlAPI + "/api/v1/carros/postcarro",
        data: JSON.stringify(carro),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
}
```

Comment: **1.** Você tem algum método que já está funcionando? **2.** Ao testar por algum auxiliar como Postman ou Fiddler este método funciona normal? **3.** Está usando Owin?

Comment: Sim, está funcionando o método de retornad dados. Não testei por nenhum auxiliar ainda. Não estou usando Owin

Comment: Poste o código do seu controller WebAPI.

Comment: Achei o problema... tem que instalar o CORS